# Use kalman filter for facial landmark detection

Tags: opencv, dlib

I would like to use the below code in kalman filter of facial landmarks detection to stabilize the landmark.

Any ideas?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks")

while True:
_, frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = detector(gray)
for face in faces:
    x1 = face.left()
    y1 = face.top()
    x2 = face.right()
    y2 = face.bottom()
    #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

    for n in range(0, 68):
        x = landmarks.part(n).x
        y = landmarks.part(n).y
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 4, (255, 0, 0), -1)


cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

key = cv2.waitKey(1)
if key == 27:
    break
```

Comment: What is the exact problem with your code?
Please be a bit more specific in your question, in order for someone to help you.

Comment: The landmarks which are generated by this code are not stable . They jiggle much more . I want to minimize the random motion of the landmarks.